# 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I search some method that said using `//`operator, but I didn't understand how to use in my program

```
def trapezoid(x, a, b, c, d):
    if x <= a:
        return 0
    if a < x <= b:
        return (x - a)/(b - a)
    if b < x <= c:
        return 1
    if c < x <= d:
        return (d - x)/(d - c)
    if d < x:
        return 0 
for i in range(-100, 100, 0.01):
    small_y = trapezoid(i, -2.46, -1.46, 1.46, 2.46)
```

I tried to use i/0.01 or i//0.01 but show same error, and I don't want to change integer from float, I just want to calculate -100, -99.99, -99.98....

Comment: `range` doesn't do floats.

Comment: another method is using np.arrange(-100, 100, 0.01)

Comment: Bad option. If you're going to use NumPy, use `numpy.linspace`. `arange` with floating point inputs has major rounding error issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(-10000, 10000, 1):
    your_float = i*.01
```